# ObservableCollection Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, observablecollection

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items{ get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

public SampleClass(){ //add 4 items
Items.Add(new Item() { Id =...},
Items.Add(new Item() { Id =...},

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<AddPage, Item>(this, "AddItem", async (obj, item) =>
        {
         Code for add new item...
        });


        public int CountItems() //Count number of items in ObservableCollection
    {
       int count = Items.Count;

        return count;
    }
```

When I call `CountItems()` from another class it return 4 , how can I update it,
so when I add a new item and call again `CountItems()` from another class will return right number? (in SampleClass it is working just fine)
Thank you guys!

Comment: You could call `MessagingCenter.Send` to add items in any other class and get the current count by invoking `SampleClass.CountItems()`

Comment: It is not static. When i make it statick SampleClass.CountItems() and ObservableCollection is statick can not use it for Binding. idk why

Comment: You need to init an instance .

Comment: What you mean, sorry i am new to xamarin.

Comment: `SampleClass sc = new SampleClass();  sc..CountItems() `